# Summing LocalTimes (Java)

Tags: java, date, time, localtime

I am trying to use Java to sum two times.

Lets say i have these LocalTimes:

```
LocalTime L1 = LocalTime.parse("2:10");


LocalTime L2 = LocalTime.parse("13:20");
```

Is there any fancy LocalTime method which makes it possible to sum hours and get 15:30  (L1+L2)

(Note: I was looking for something in the time or date package), without String butchering.

Comment: You're using the wrong abstraction.

Comment: `LocalTime.parse("13:20").plus(Duration.ofHours(2).plusMinutes(10))`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `LocalTime` marks a **point** in time, not a duration. You cannot add two points in time - it doesn't make sense.

`LocalTime` does have a `plus()` method, but it requires a `TemporalAmount` (a `Period` or `Duration`) and not a `LocalTime`. You can do what you want by converting a `LocalTime` to a `Duration` by using `Duration.ofNanos(localTime.toNanoOfDay())`, so you'd do something like `l1.plus(Duration.ofNanos(l2.toNanoOfDay()))` (this basically means you're treating the second `LocalTime` not as a point in time, but as the amount of time that elapsed since the start of the day)

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Wilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232645/642706) is correct. I'll elaborate.

You have conflated two key concepts:

- Point in time, a moment, a point on the timeline
- Span of time, an amount of time *not* attached to the timeline.

An example of the first is agreeing to meet you for lunch next Wednesday at 12:30 PM in `Africa/Casablanca` time zone. An example of the second is a school’s policy that the students’ lunch period lasts 50 minutes.

- For the first, use the `Instant` (always in UTC), `OffsetDateTime` (offset from UTC as a count of hours and minutes), or `ZonedDateTime` (a time zone such as `Pacific/Auckland` assigned) classes.
- For the second, use the `Period` (a count of years, months, and days) or `Duration` (a total number of whole seconds plus a fractional second) classes.

For a date-only value without time of day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`. For a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone, use `LocalTime`.

Your examples suggest that you had two events occur, one elapsing a couple minutes and one taking thirteen minutes. So we need the `Duration` class. The `LocalTime` class does not apply to your problem.

You confusingly use time-of-day notation to represent such spans of time. Better to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for such strings. The [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing or generating strings.

```
Duration d1 = Duration.parse( "PT2M10S" ) ;
Duration d2 = Duration.parse( "PT13M20S" ) ;

Duration d3 = d1.plus( d2 ) ;
```

> d3.toString(): PT15M30S